# Git diff from remote location

Tags: git, sublimetext2, remote-server, git-diff, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Not sure if this is possible,

I have a repo with beanstalk,
I have it setup on a production server, just for pulls.
I have another on my development server, where I do all the changes and push to master.

The development server is running ubuntu, the machine I use is windows and I ssh into the dev server to use git commands.
I use 'sublime text' on windows to edit files, but I want to be able to git diff, merge conflicts using sublime, but this require git - after installing a local git it still doesn't work (as i assume because the repo isn't within access of the local git installation).

Can I do what I want or is it not possible?

Thanks

Comment: do you have a git plugin installed in Sublime Text?

Comment: Is Git installed on the remote server?